# How to set vertical distance between cards in GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I've simple `card.xml`layout in which one image is presented, it's size is 300px x 300px.

For displaying cards I've made Recycler View and RecyclerAdapter, and initialized all stuff to works in form of Grid Layout.

**My problem is:** views are displayed but vertical distance between two rows of cards is to much, I want to get it closer.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

For next row I must scroll:

[image]

Is there any to fix it?

**card layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/java"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Adapter**

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        return (ViewHolder) new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ViewHolder(View itemView){
      super(itemView);}

    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
   RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

PS: this's all laboratory project, so things like dynamically initialized cards content have been skipped.

Comment: add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in imageview should do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem is in the layout of the `CardView`.
Try to replace `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/java"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```